# How can i split this function

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a basic Backtracking algorithm which checks if i can place tetris on a map, all function are simple, check_map which check if there is place on the map, place_map which allow to place tetris on my map and delete_tetri which delete tetri on the map.

By convention, I would like to keep my functions to a maximum of 25 lines, so I need to *split* or *refactor* this code into multiple smaller functions.

I am having trouble achieving this because keeping track of all the variables is difficult.

```
int     fillit(char *map, char **tab, int map_size, int j)
{
 int map_index;
 int nb_block;
 int **tetri;
 int *hash_index;

 tetri = tetri_stock_hash(tab, j, map_size);
 map_index = 0;
 nb_block = 0;
 if (!(hash_index = (int *)ft_memalloc(sizeof(hash_index) * (j + 1))))
    return (-1);
 while (nb_block != j)
 {
     if (check_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, map_index) == 1)
     {
        hash_index[nb_block] = map_index;
        place_in_map(tetri, map, &nb_block, &map_index);
     }
     else if (check_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, map_index) == -1)
        map_index++;
     else if (check_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, map_index) == 2)
     {
        if (nb_block == 0)
        {
            map_size++;
            map = map_generate(4 + map_size);
            fillit(map, tab, map_size, j);
            return (1);
        }
        nb_block--;
        delete_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, hash_index[nb_block]);
        map_index = hash_index[nb_block] + 1;
     }
 }
 a_z(tetri, map, hash_index, j);
 map_print_color(map);
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by 'split'? (For example, do you want the `fillit` function to be 'split' into subroutines?)

Comment: I would like my function make a maximum of 25 lines, so i need to "split" or cut this function in several parts. But as i cant keep data of each variable its difficult.

Comment: Right. The usual way do do this in C, while avoiding globals, is to create a structure with all necessary storage and pass a pointer to that structure to all functions that need to access/modify data in it.

Comment: Don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your post. Evaluate `check_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, map_index)` just once as a "`switch`-expression". *Don't knock yourself out trying to adhere to guidelines like the one quoted*. (When the majority of "on-line" terminals displayed 24 or 25 lines on a 12 inch tube, a formatting style using less lines was common (place curly brace in same line as control structure). It still saves place to combine declaration and initialisation of variables.)

Comment: The computation of the size to allocate looks fatally wrong: I'm used to `sizeof *hash_index * (j + 1)`

Comment: This style of question, where you have a functional routine but you want opinions on style or help with refactoring is better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (code review is not an option for migration that I can access in the review queues)

Comment: Your question is about refactoring, but if your current code works, is refactoring necessary? We're talking about reducing a 39 line function (including variables and spaces) down to 25 lines here. Refactoring will result in many more lines of code and your logic is pretty well reduced into sub-routines already. IMO this is the result of good refactoring, you've done a good job, sit back, have a beer and appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to just reduce the line count, then perhaps you can try this:

```
int     fillit(char *map, char **tab, int map_size, int j) {
 int map_index = 0, nb_block = 0, **tetri, *hash_index;
 tetri = tetri_stock_hash(tab, j, map_size);
 if (!(hash_index = (int *)ft_memalloc(sizeof(hash_index) * (j + 1))))
    return (-1);
 while (nb_block != j) {
     switch (check_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, map_index)) {
         case 1: hash_index[nb_block] = map_index;
        place_in_map(tetri, map, &nb_block, &map_index); break;
        case -1: map_index++; break;
        case 2: if (nb_block == 0) {
            map_size++;
            map = map_generate(4 + map_size);
            fillit(map, tab, map_size, j);
            return (1);
        }
        nb_block--;
        delete_in_map(tetri, map, nb_block, hash_index[nb_block]);
        map_index = hash_index[nb_block] + 1; break;
     }
 }
 a_z(tetri, map, hash_index, j);
 map_print_color(map);
 return (0);
}
```

This is exactly what you wrote, I am unaware of algorithm or logic behind it, just removed excess lines and a little tinkering here and there.